# How to obfuscate strings in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which calls a script file. It is going to pass a secret to the script file.

What I would like is for the secret not to be shown in standard out.

According to the ansible documentation, `no_log: true` can be used however this will not work when used in a `ANSIBLE_DEBUG` env variable is set `true`.

What I am also finding is that in the task "Set Execution File and parameters", the variables are being displayed even with `no_log: true`.

```yaml
---
- block:  

  - name: Set Execution File and parameters
    set_fact:
      scriptfile: "{{ansible_user_dir}}\\scripts\\host_check.ps1"
      params: " -servername '{{the_host_name}}' -secret {{my_secret}}"
  
  - name: Execute script
    win_command: powershell.exe "{{scriptfile}}" "{{params}}"
    no_log: True

  rescue:
    - debug:
        msg: "Play failed"
```

I would like to replace the `my_secret` variable with `*******`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `no_log: true` is all you can do. Ansible will need to know your secret to use it and anybody who can set `ANSIBLE_DEBUG` can also just edit your playbook to display the secret. So as much as you hide it, it can always be revealed.

You have, however, the possibility to encrypt the secret using `ansible-vault` and pass the password to ansible, so nobody except you (or has the password) can use (and my this display) the secret.

This is how you encrypt a value (`<secret-value>` in this case):

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string --ask-vault-pass '<secret-value>' --name 'secret'
```

You will be asked for a password (I used `test` here) and then will get something that looks like this:

```
secret: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          36323534396462626132653332653266393832306337336164373834626330373132363136633865
          6161623130363364643138633236306334313833663535380a666261383838313631396264626534
          66373637653937616231353361633635353238333630303563343630333161626137396332616263
          3966356531613234370a633331333862616164386130663262613430316630373230373833313330
          6265
```

You place that in your inventory like this (just an example what it should look like, you need to put in your hosts and other variables):

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    your-host:
  vars:
    secret: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          36323534396462626132653332653266393832306337336164373834626330373132363136633865
          6161623130363364643138633236306334313833663535380a666261383838313631396264626534
          66373637653937616231353361633635353238333630303563343630333161626137396332616263
          3966356531613234370a633331333862616164386130663262613430316630373230373833313330
          6265
    the_host_name: host.name
    ansible_user_dir: 'C:\\some\\dir'
```

Then you can do this in your playbook:

```yaml
---
- block:
  - name: Execute script
    win_command: 'powershell.exe "{{ ansible_user_dir }}\\scripts\\host_check.ps1" -servername "{{ the_host_name }}" -secret "{{ my_secret }}"'
    no_log: true
  rescue:
    - debug:
        msg: "Play failed"
```

You need to run it with `--ask-vault-pass` like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i your-inventory.yml your-playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

It will ask you for the password every time you run it, so make sure to keep it somewhere.
If you are using multiple encrypted values in one run, you need to use the same password to encrypt all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will study it carefully. I just wondered how/if this is a solution that can be used within ansible tower.